# Is it possible to compute the volume of a cone on a inner product space?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis, inner-products, topological-vector-spaces

This is a matter of curiosity for me. Volumes are often compute using triple integration. But is it possible to compute volumes on a vector space with an inner product defined on that vector space?

Comment: If the space is finite dimensional, the usual construction of Lebesgue measure can be used to make sense of volumes. In the infinite dimensional case, there is (as far as I know) no canonical measure like the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: If the vector space is finite-dimensional, aren't you talking about change of variables in multivariate calculus? (The Jacobian matrix is the positive definite square root of the matrix representation of the inner product.)